# Bounds for the expected value of the Kolmogorov-Smirnoff loss function

Tags: nonparametric, loss-functions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, risk, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

Let
$$
\mathcal{F}=\{F:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}: \text{$F$ is the CDF of some probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$}\}.
$$
Consider the *loss function*, $L:\mathcal F\times\mathcal F\to\mathbb R$, defined by
$$
L(F,G) = \sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|F(x) - G(x)|.
$$
(This is just the metric induced by the $L^\infty$-norm.)

Let $\Theta$ be a subset of $\mathcal{F}$.
For $\theta\in\Theta$ and a random sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ drawn from $\theta$, let $\hat{\theta}(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ be the associated empirical distribution function:
$$
\hat\theta(X_1,\ldots,X_n)(x) = \frac 1 n\sum_{i=1}^n I(X_i\leq x)
$$
Are there "large" sets $\Theta$ for which one can one explicitly compute, or bound, the risk $R$ associated to the loss function $L$ in terms of $n$ and $\Theta$, where $R$ is defined by
$$
R(\theta,\hat{\theta}) = E_\theta[L(\theta,\hat\theta(X_1,\ldots,X_n))]?
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to get an upper bound for $\Theta = \mathcal{F}$ using the Dvoretzky-Kiefer-Wolfowitz (DKW) inequality and
$EL = \int_0^\infty\Pr(L>u)du$, see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz_inequality#The_DKW_inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality#The_DKW_inequality)

The DKW inequality gives us
$$R(\theta,\hat\theta) = \int_0^\infty \Pr\left(L(\theta,\hat\theta)>u\right)du \leq 2\int_0^\infty e^{-2nu^2}du.$$

I'm not sure if tighter bounds exist for $\Theta\subset\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).